# Order database entries based on multiple conditions using linq

Tags: c#, database, linq, group-by, sql-order-by

I need to sort entries in a database based on various conditions. Each entry can have one of three statuses depending on some of its attributes.

Group A (status "locked"):

```
IsLocked == true;
```

Group B (status "inactive"):

```
 IsLocked == false &&
(IsApproved == false ||
 Supplier.IsActive == false ||
 Supplier.IsDeleted == true ||
 ProductGroup.IsActive == false ||
 ProductGroup.IsDeleted == true ||
 Products.All(x => x.BestBeforeDate < DateTime.Now) == true)
```

Group C (status "active"):

```
IsLocked == false &&
IsApproved == true &&
Supplier.IsActive == true &&
Supplier.IsDeleted == false &&
ProductGroup.IsActive == true &&
ProductGroup.IsDeleted == false &&
Products.Any(x => x.BestBeforeDate > DateTime.Now) == true)
```

I would like to avoid running over a list, splitting it up into three lists and appending them again afterwards. Is there a way to achieve this using Linq? Can I group the entries by these conditions and then having a sort on the groups? If so, How would I do this?

Comment: You don't need to compare boolean values with true/false. Simply use `!IsLocked && IsApproved && Supplier.IsActive && ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the extension method

```
OrderBy(x => x.IsLocked).ThenBy(...)
                        .ThenBy(...)
```

Comment: You're welcome. I remember I was quite impressed when I discovered that the OrderBy returns an OrderedEnumerable, which proposes a ThenBy method.

Comment: Indeed, that's quite amazing. I'd have never figured.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var results = query
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.IsLocked)
    .ThenByDescending(x => !x.IsLocked && (!x.IsApproved ... ))
    .ThenByDescending(x => !x.IsLocked && (x.IsApproved ... ));
```

Using [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx) / [`ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending.aspx) will make items which meet the criteria appear first, followed by items which do not. If you want to make items which do not meet the criteria appear first, simply use [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) / [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the linq .OrderBy and .ThenBy methods to put the items in the order you suggest, and then run a SaveChanges() if you are using the EF.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where OP said the collection is being modified. Why would you need to call `SaveChanges`?

Comment: "I need to sort entries in a database based on various conditions."

Comment: Indeed the database shall not be modified, but the user will have to see the sorted collection. Therefore I need to sort them and return the sorted entries to the user.
Anyways, your answer was correct, but unfortunately not the first one.